# How do I improve the speech synthesis in Firefox Quantum

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

The speech synthesis voice that is returned in a Firefox Quantum browser on an Ubuntu 18 LTS OS, is not very good.

I've tested it on other OS.  The voice returned with the same Javascript API on an Android OS and Windows OS is very good. Is the problem with Firefox Quantum or the Linux OS?

```
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
     // Synthesis support ok
    var wordsToSay = words.value; 
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[1]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
    msg.voiceURI = 'native';
    msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
    msg.rate = 0.7; // 0.1 to 10
    msg.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
    msg.text = wordsToSay;
    msg.lang = 'en-UK';

    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

I would expect the voice to be good on Linux, but perhaps I'm biased!

Comment: Have you looked at the voices returned by getVoices? Maybe there's more than one for the UK? Secondly, easier to make msg.lang = msg.voice.lang so there's never a mis-match.

Comment: The problem's with Firefox - Chrome on Ubuntu works fine.